# Rails serialized JSON to string gives error on mysql JSON field

Tags: mysql, json, string, replace

I have an old table which used to save json to a string sql field using the Rails ActiveRecord serializer. I created a new table with the field datatype as JSON which was introduced in MySQL 5.7. But directly copying the data from the old field to the new one gives me JSON error saying the json structure is wrong.

More specifically the problem is with unicode characters which my database does not support as of yet and the database is too large to just migrate everything to support it.

I am looking for a way to migrate the data from the old field to the new JSON field

I have seen that replacing `\u`for the unicode character to `\\u` in the JSON string solved the issue but I am not just able to do this:

```
update table_name set column_name=REPLACE(column_name, '\u', '\\u');
```

since it gives an error again

```
ERROR 3140 (22032): Invalid JSON text: "Invalid escape character in string." at position 564 in value for column 'table_name.column_name'.
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. Are you sure this is what you need to do to fix whatever problem you're trying to solve?  2. What problem are you *really* trying to solve? How did you get data into the column that was invalid?  You shouldn't be manipulating JSON columns without using JSON functions, and data in JSON columns by definition shouldn't need to be directly manipulated.

Comment: So this is old data that was serialized using Activerecord serializer in rails, which I migrated to a json column in a new table, but I get error when parsing this JSON on ruby. I changed \u to \\u manually in JSON and saw that it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

for sql updating table values \u to \\u :

```
 update table_name set column_name=REPLACE(column_name, '\\u', '\\\\u') [where condition];
```